# Finding the Tile from a MouseListener

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a chess game utilizing the `MouseListener` `interface`. (No JButtons!)
After a click, I am able to find the `[x, y]` location of the click on the `JFrame`, but I want to find the tile.

The chess board is an `8 x 8` grid. A tile is a location on that grid (So `[1, 3]` is a tile.)

My thought is to divide the `xPosition` by the `tileWidth`, and the `yPosition` by the `tileHeight`. I should be able to find the `tileHeight` and `tileWidth` by getting the size of the screen and divide it by the number of tiles (Which will always be `8`, because a chess board is `8 x 8`)

This works for the most part, but as I click closer to the edges of each tile, the result for the equation above is inaccurate.

```java
/** 
 * @param screen The JPanel that contains the tiles (Will always be the size of the entire board)
 * @param pos The (x, y) position of the click
 * @return The tile found from the click
 */
public Tile getTile(Screen screen, Pos pos) {

    int x = (pos.x / (screen.getWidth() / Board.WIDTH)); // When trying to typecast to a double, then back to an int, the result become more inaccurate.
    int y = (pos.y / (screen.getHeight() / Board.HEIGHT));
    System.out.println(new Pos(x, y));

    return tiles[y][x];
}
```

EDIT: My `JPanel` is the same size as the `JContentPane` (Area in the JFrame)

Comment: Do you need to take into account the insets of the screen?

Comment: Does your JPanel fill your whole JFrame?

Comment: The high-level answer is: You have to make sure that the coordinates that are used for **painting** are the same that are used for computing the tile that was clicked. Apragmatic approach *could* be to try out `int x = (int)(pos.x / ((double)screen.getWidth() / Board.WIDTH));`, but it all depends on how you are *painting* the tiles.

Comment: @Marco13, Already mentioned that I tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is partially with equation. I should have stuck with the typecasting shown below:

```java
int x = (int) (pos.x / ((double) screen.getWidth() / Board.WIDTH));
int y = (int) (pos.y / ((double) screen.getHeight() / Board.HEIGHT));
```

But the real issue is that the `MouseEvent` `interface` counts the top left of the **JFRAME** as `point[0, 0]`. This means that the top left of the **JCONTENTPANE** is actually going to be at `point[~10, ~40]` (I say about because the point may vary per computer, and how close I am personally able to click on the JFrame). If you ant to find the exact value of the extra space, get the `JFrame`'s size and subtract the `JContentPane`'s size.

```java
int x = (int) ((pos.x - X_OFFSET) / ((double) screen.getWidth()  / Board.WIDTH));
int y = (int) ((pos.y - Y_OFFSET) / ((double) screen.getHeight() / Board.HEIGHT));
```

Where `X_OFFSET = 8` and `Y_OFFSET = 38`

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I was completely WRONG!

Assuming your whole `JPanel` is filling your Whole `JFrame`, and your parameter `pos` starts a [0,0] on the topleft corner of your JPanel and JFrame and ends with its max dimensions at the bottomright corner, your calculations are in fact correct:

Lets say your JPanel and JFrame is 1000px in width, and 1000px in height.

Lets do a click on 500px horizontally(left-right) that means right in the middle of the horizontal axis (X)

```
      Click
        |
        +
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
```

That would evaluate to: `500/(1000/8) = 500/(125) = 4`,
which would be correct when we say that a click exactly between column 4 and 5 would be a click on column 4, e.g. `tiles[y][4-1];` *remember arrays start at 0*

When doing `(499/(1000/8) = 499/(125) = 3,992` which when casted to an int would be 3 **(casts drop all decimal numbers)** which is correct.

When doing `(501/(1000/8) = 501/(125) = 4,008` which when casted to an int would also be 4. Which is also correct.

When on the left 50% of the screen (499px) you would want to have col tile[y][3] and when on the right 50% of the screen you would want to have tile[y][4]

this means your calculations are correct.

The only thing I can think of is that you are getting a wrong mouse position, or your JFrame is not fully filling your JPanel.

Try printing out your mouse position whenever your mouse moves, and then check if all is correct

Comment: I'm sorry, at one point you use my equation is correct and at another point you said it is not correct? Could you explain this?

Comment: @CJCrafter sorry that was a leftover of my previous answer. I then realized you DID calculate correctly, and came to the conclusion, that only your mouse position could be calculated wrong, or the frame does not fill the whole jpanel, in wich case the x and y pos of your mouse could be wrong again... (depending on how you get then)